# Create a custom XDG_DIR with custom icon

Tags: gnome, icons, freedesktop

I'd like to create a custom XDG_CUSTOM_DIR directory in my home directory pointing to $HOME/Custom and assign an icon to it.

I've done:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set CUSTOM ~/Custom
```

So far so good... ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs has been changed acordingly.

Now: how do I assign an icon to it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as the XDG specification defines specific directory names only for certain roles (example `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR`, `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR`, or `XDG_MUSIC_DIR`; try `man xdg-user-dirs-update` to see them all).  Various libraries (e.g. glib or GTK+ for GNOME) implement the spec and will perform special operations for only those directories in the spec. So custom directories are not supported.

Off course you could add support to `XDG_CUSTOM_DIR` in GNOME for your own use. It would require coding skills to patch and compile libraries and applications to support this additional directory. For instance in glib look to https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/glocalfileinfo.c#n1591 and https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gutils.c#n1541 to see how it is handled.

Comment: So I should try to hack the way gnome (in my case) treats those directories?... Any hints on how to do that?